# Bash Exit Status Always Fails Comparison

Tags: bash, prompt, ps1, exitstatus

In my .bashrc...

```
46 function exitstatus()
47 {
48  local a=0
49  local s=$1
50  s=$s+1
51  a=$a+1
52  echo -n ' arg1='$s' a='$a
53  s=$1
54  a=0
55  echo  ' arg1='$s' a='$a
56
57  if [[ "$s" = "$a" ]]; then
58      echo "true"
59  else
60      echo "false"
61  fi
62 }
63
64 function myprompt {
65  local        ss=\$?
66  unset PS1
67  PS1="exit:\$? var:$ss exitstatus $ss $(exitstatus $ss) \n\t $ "
68 }
69 myprompt
```

exitstatus always evaluates to `false`, even when variable `s` and `a` appear to be the same string:

```
23:36:55 $ true
exit:0 var:0 exitstatus 0  arg1=0+1 a=0+1 arg1=0 a=0
false
23:36:56 $ false
exit:1 var:1 exitstatus 1  arg1=1+1 a=0+1 arg1=1 a=0
false
```

Lines 50 and 52 have demonstrated to me that `s` is being treated as a string so I compare it as a string in line 57.  The comparison works as expected if I compare `s` to itself or `a` to itself because exitstatus always evaluates to `true`.  For some reason `exit status $?` as an argument to exitstatus is not being handled as I expect.

What am I missing?

Comment: Except that your function is overly complicated (I would write the comparision as `if (( s == 0 )); then ...` instead), I can not reproduce the problem. Of course it is odd that you seem to set your `PS1` once in your .bashrc and never reset it (when are you calling `myprompt` again?), but this does not explain the output you have posted. What do you get if you try on the command line `s=0; a=0; [[ "$s" = "$a" ]] && echo true`? And, instead of cluttering `exitstatus` with `echo` statements, I would debug it by running it under `set -x`.

Comment: The `exitstatus` function is run only once, when `myprompt` runs (try `declare -p PS1` to see what it sets). To make it run each time the prompt is displayed, use `PS1="... \$(exitstatus $ss) ...` instead of `PS1="... $(exitstatus $ss) ...`. Although really this whole thing is much more complicated than it should be. At the very least, rather than the messing around with escaped dollar signs and the `ss` variable, just set `PS1` to a single-quoted string.

Comment: I posted an answer that explains why you get a static `false` or static `true`. I would also help you writing a better `exitstatus()`, but I really don't understand what you want to do with `$a` and `$s`. If you post you final requirement (e.g. "my prompt should do ...") I'd be glad to help you out.

Comment: Ultimately I want my prompt to display the date, my username, the host I'm using, the pwd, a new line, and the time in either green or red text depending on the success of the last command.  The issues I had led me to suspect that the single quotes weren't interpolating the color escape characters correctly and that is why I moved to double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Since you defined `PS1="..."` with double quotes, the subshell `$(exitstatus ...)` is only evaluated once when the shell starts up. After that, the result from that one evaluation is a literal part of your prompt and won't change anymore.

#### Minimal Example

In this interactive shell session I execute one command per second. `date +%s` prints the seconds of the current time. I use `true` as command because it prints nothing.

```
$ PS1="$(date +%s) "
23 true
23 true
23 PS1='$(date +%s) '
26 true
27 true
```

As we can see, with double quotes the subshell is evaluated only once whereas with single quotes the subshell is expanded each time the prompt is printed. Of course you could also write `PS1="\$(date +%s) "` to the get an updating prompt.

Comment: Initially I was assigning PS1 with single quotes and the comparison to exit status was happening correctly, but...
the color of my prompt was not changing as desired.  I assumed the single quotes weren't interpolating my e[m color escapes correctly but I just tried it again and it worked.
I think that with double quotes the results of executing exitstatus was not updating with every command execution, but was preserving the results of the last command executed prior to sourcing .bashrc.

Answer (score 0):

This is what ultimately worked.  I got rid of myprompt and used `exitstatus` to change the colors of my prompt:

```
function exitstatus { if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then echo -e "\e[48;5;52m"; fi; }
unset PS1 PS2 PS4
PS1='$(exitstatus) $'
```